# Prove that sequence converges quadratically to 1

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

Problem: Prove that sequence $x_n=1+\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{2^n}$ converges quadratically to 1.

I tried to use the definition:
$|x_{n+1}-x^*|\leq C |x_n-x^*|^{\alpha}$, where $\alpha=2$ (because of quadratic) and $C$ is a constant.

$
|x_{n+1}-1|=\left| 1+\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{2^{n+1}}-1 \right|=
\left| \left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{2^{n}+2} \right|=
\left| \left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{2^{n}}\cdot \left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{2} \right|
$

I tried simplifying other ways, but still didn't get the result of the form: $C |x_n-x^*|^{\alpha}$. Can someone help me find a way to show that it converges to 1 quadratically?

Comment: You need to bound $\frac{|x_{n+1}-1|}{ |x_n-1|^{2}}$

Comment: Were you ultimately able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

This is problematic, because the stated result is incorrect.

We discard the irrelevant constant and focus on $$y_n = n^{-2^n}.$$ It is clear that $y_n$ tends to $0$ as $n$ tends to infinity. It is conjectured that the order of convergence is $\alpha=2$. It is clear that $y_n > 0$ for all $n$, hence the fraction $f_n = y_{n+1}/y_n^2$ is defined. We have
$$ f_n = \frac{y_{n+1}}{y_n^2} = \frac{(n+1)^{-2^{n+1}}}{\left(n^{-2^n}\right)^2} = \frac{n^{2^{n+1}}}{(n+1)^{2^{n+1}}} = \left( \frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{2^{n+1}}.$$
We are interested in the limit of $f_n$ when $n$ tends to infinity. We have $$0 \leq f_n = \left( 1 - \frac{1}{n+1} \right)^{2^{n+1}} \leq \left[ \exp\left(- \frac{1}{n+1}\right)\right]^{2^{n+1}} = \exp \left( - \frac{2^{n+1}}{n+1} \right) \rightarrow 0, \quad n \rightarrow \infty, \quad n \in \mathbb{N}.$$
Here we have actively used the inequality $$\forall x \ge 0 \: : \: 1 - x \leq \exp(-x).$$
as well as the identity $$ \forall a, b \in \mathbb{R} \: : \: (e^a)^b = e^{ab}.$$
The squeeze lemma now implies that $$f_n \rightarrow 0, \quad n \rightarrow \infty, \quad n \in \mathbb{N}.$$
This shows that the sequence $y_n$ tends to zero *faster* than quadratically and the conjecture is actually false. Quadratic convergence is characterized by
$$ \frac{|x - x_{n+1}|}{|x-x_n|^2} \rightarrow c, \quad n \rightarrow \infty, \quad n \in \mathbb{N}.$$
where $c$ must be strictly greater than $0$. We have $c = 0$.

It is entirely possible that the original author meant to write: "Show that the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ given by $x_n = 1 + \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2^n}$ converges at least quadratically to $1$".